# Where can I find the current water level of the Kineret to see the effect of mentioning Morid Hageshem?

Tags: product-recommendation, internet, eretz-yisrael, water, geshem-tal-ruach

Throughout the winter we pray Mashiv HaRuach UMorid HaGeshem. My understanding is that it is said for Eretz Yisroel dwellers (unlike V'sain Tal Umatar LBracha which is said for your locale). As we pray for it I am interested in knowing if there is an online source to find out what is the current water level of the Kineret?

Comment: Move to close as off-topic.

Comment: It's a major indicator of a status that can formally trigger lots of prayers ...

Comment: @Gershon: you could say the same thing, for example, about "who is responsible for the flotilla deaths." And yet that is in the Area51 proposal as a good example of an off-topic question.

Comment: @R'Gershon, what R'Alex said. Moreover, note that the water level in the _Kineres_ is connected to the people of Israel, not just the Jews of _EY_. @R'IM, yes. So is the makeup of the U.S. Congress; so is the proximity of an asteroid to Earth.

Comment: Doesn't water availability in the Land of Israel have particular religious significance? Aren't there fasts triggered specifically by it?

Comment: @R'IM: re fasts: true. Does that make this question on-topic?

Comment: Isaac makes a good point about this having a particular relationship to halachah. But consider the practicalities: we chutzniks aren't going to be declaring fasts on our own depending on what we see at kinbot. I doubt any individual Jews in Eretz Yisrael would be doing so either - any such fasts would be proclaimed by rabbanim. So the question "what data is taken into consideration in deciding when to declare fasts" is certainly on-topic, but I'm not so sure that the question as phrased is.

Comment: Halacha-related questions here are not necessarily lema'aseh for the asker. (In fact, we run into website-ask-posek problems when they are.) In addition, it seems to me that someone could be inspired by the particular emphasis that Halacha puts on the water situation in the Land of Israel and want to therefore keep track of that situation personally as a matter of, inter alia, religious concern. I agree that this is an edge case and not so different from, e.g., "How many rocket attacks has Israel suffered in the past year?", but I'm inclined to give it the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: What is the connection between the first part of the question and the second part of the question? Please elaborate.

Comment: When I saw the title, I wanted to close as off topic.  But seeing that its connected directly to a prayer said, I think it's fully on topic,.  I'm going to change the question title to reflect its ontopicness

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See:

- http://savethekinneret.com/ (chart is a bit messy, though)
- http://www.israelweather.co.il/kineret.asp (in hebrew)

Comment: I follow Kinbot and its both really neat and disheartening.  After weeks of rain the damn thing is still at the same level as 3 months ago!

Comment: However, if you look at the profile info of Kinbot you can also get a link to a chart showing the water level.   I tweet the water level of Lake Kinneret/the Sea of Galilee, Israel. A graph updated every time I tweet: bit.ly/3mHein + full data: http://bit.ly/tIRmi 
http://bit.ly/57Nt0g

Comment: KinBot last tweeted on 14 December 2015, so it's probably defunct. I'm editing it out of this answer, leaving the other two sources, which both appear to be live as of now.