# Mah inyan Shmita eitzel the price of tea in China?

Tags: money, chutz-laaretz, shmita

I saw some red peppers in an American grocery store labelled "Product of Israel".  I have never seen that before, and my guess is that since it's a shmitta year, there is less of an Israeli domestic market and it makes Israeli produce in the US relatively cheap.  Is that a thing?

What is the effect of shmitta on the price of Israeli exports?  Does this impact the availability of shmitta-year Israeli produce in American markets such that I should be on the lookout, or was this a fluke occurrence?

Comment: Feel free to vote to close as off-topic.  I think I'd be tempted to do the same.

Comment: I think this question could be made on topic by having a motivation to find out how Shmitta affects the availability of Israeli products in American grocery stores, as such potential availability has significant Kashrus implications.

Comment: I think the edit makes it more on-topic

Comment: Charles, much .

Comment: The need to make sure that one deals halachically with shemitta produce outside of Israel, is independent of the reason that the produce has arrived there.

Comment: Charles, are you asking about *availability* of these fruits (which I would vote to close), or the *halakha* of what to do about this?

Comment: @Matt I'm asking something along these lines (I'm not defending it staying open. I think it should be moved to [economics.se]): Normally, as a diaspora Jew, I don't see any Israeli produce in my grocery store.  Does shmita increase the availability or reduce the costs of Israeli produce enough to change that to the extent that I should pay even more special attention to whether produce in my grocery store is from Israel?

Comment: I don't understand. Why would you pay more special attention to whether produce is grown in israel? Is it because you care about halakha, perhaps?

Comment: @Matt yes, that's implied. Sorry.  It should read: "...to the extent that I, as a Jew who cares about observance of shmita _and maaser_, should pay even more special attention to whether produce in my grocery store is from Israel"

Comment: In that case I don't think it's off-topic (but, that's just like, my opinion, man). Is there any question on the meta about "questions of determining metzius/reality for Jewish-related purposes"? If feel like there are a bunch of those

Comment: @Matt Consider http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/6255/759

Comment: @DoubleAA that particular question has no halakhic import (I think), but i agree in theory. I was also thinking about the question regarding blood spots in eggs, and I'm sure there are more. No meta-question about this then, huh?

Comment: @Matt If there is it's hard enough to search for that we could use an extra [signpost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144608/166155). Go ahead and ask.

Comment: @DoubleAA my browser has been having trouble with the meta of late (though I don't think that [this](http://xkcd.com/1447/) is the problem)

Answer (score 2):

I've seen Israeli peppers in American supermarkets in the wintertime every so often, shmittah or not.

I don't think it's so much a function of shmittah as climate and growing conditions.

In shmittah years, it's probably best to avoid buying them. In non-shmittah years, I heard my rabbi say that the best thing is to learn how to tithe them properly, then buy them and do so; but if you don't know how to properly tithe them, then try to avoid them.

I've also seen frozen carrots, product of Israel, with an OU on the label. I asked the OU, and was told they have been properly tithed.

Comment: While that may be true of vegetables, you should really avoid buying uncertified Israeli fruits, as much of it is Orlah that can't be sold in Israel.