# What Have Modern Posqim said about Nuclear Weapons?

Tags: halacha, technology, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, army-military-war

I'm looking to find *teshuvot* from modern *posqim* that discuss the permissability of possessing and using nuclear weapons.

Comment: Why would you think it is prohibited to own them or to detonate one or that halacha has anything to say about it? (Do you mean to ask about killing civilians in war? If so you should just ask that.) Why tag [tag:eretz-yisrael] when you don't discuss the land or state of Israel at all?

Comment: Unless the tag implies that the question is about what Posqim have said about the State of Israel owning and using nukes, @DoubleAA? izmaragad, if that was your intention, please consider [edit]ing that into the question body to make that clear.

Comment: @Shokhet That would still be an invalid use of a tag. One shouldn't need to look at the tags (or the title) of a question-post to understand it or know if it is on topic.

Comment: @DoubleAA Those on Arqade would [disagree with you](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2196), though I'm inclined to believe that you are correct.

Comment: When reading this, I remembered how Berkeley, CA has a municipal ban on nuclear weapons... dina d'malchusa?

Comment: izmaragad, if you mean to ask specifically about Israel please edit that into the question (and in that case you can put the tag back).  While a few SE sites let tags convey scope that's not otherwise in the question, on this site we want questions to be complete, with tags for categorization.  Thanks!

Comment: DoubleAA, @Monica, I'm wondering if that policy re: tags is documented in Meta?

Comment: @Yishai http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/51408/mah-inyan-shmita-eitzel-the-price-of-tea-in-china#comment136440_51408

Comment: "If a man comes to kill you, rise early and kill him first" - Berachot 58a perhaps this applies to Iran who openly stated their goal of destroying Israel?

Answer (score 1):

The [Lubavitcher Rebbe](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:v_l-yF_zXyAJ:www.moshiach.net/blind/hebrew/dm44.htm+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) said in Parshas Mishpatim 5752:

> א. ידוע1 שכל המאורעות שבעולם הם בהשגחה פרטית, ויש בהם לימוד והוראה בעבודת
>   האדם לקונו, ועאכו"כ בנוגע למאורעות כלליים ועיקריים הקשורים עם מדינות גדולות
>   וחשובות )שבהם נמצא רוב מנין ורוב בנין דבנ"י בזמן הגלות2( בעלי השפעה ומנהיגות כל
>   העולם כולו, שגם הלימוד וההוראה ממאורעות אלו הוא בענין כללי ועיקרי בעבודת האדם
>   לקונו.
>
> ועד"ז בנוגע להמאורעות דימים אלה:
>
> לכל לראש - המאורע שאירע בערב שבת זה3, שבו התאספו והתכנסו יחדיו ראשי מדינות 
>   גדולות וחשובות בעולם, ובראשם נשיאי שתי המעצמות הגדולות, והחליטו והכריזו על
>   תקופה חדשה ביחסי מדינות העולם - ביטול מצב של מלחמות בין מדינות העולם, שיתבטא
>   גם בצמצום וביטול כלי נשק, ועד לשלום ואחדות, שיתוף פעולה ועזרה הדדית בין מדינות
>   העולם לטובת האנושות כולה.
>
> וקדם למאורע זה )בהשגחה פרטית( נאומו של נשיא מדינה זו לאומה כולה )באור ליום
>   הרביעי, "קמי שבתא"4, התחלת ערב שבת זה5(, שבו הודיע והכריז על פעולותיו בצמצום
>   וביטול כלי נשק, וניצול הכספים )שלא ינתנו לרכישת כלי נשק( כדי להוסיף בעניני הכלכלה
>   של בני המדינה - הכרזה שאושרה ע"י "בית הנבחרים", שבו נקבעים חוקי המדינה שיש להם
>   תוקף ע"פ תורה )"דינא דמלכותא דינא"6(.
>
> ויש להתבונן בהלימוד וההוראה ממאורע זה, וגם בפרטי הענינים דהמאורע - מקומו וזמנו,
>   כולל שייכותו לתוכנו של הזמן בתורה7, בפרשת השבוע8, כדלקמן.
>
> ב. הלימוד וההוראה ממאורע זה הוא בענין כללי ועיקרי בעבודתם של בנ"י )"מעשינו
>   ועבודתינו כל זמן משך הגלות"9( - "להביא לימות המשיח10":
>
> מהיעודים דהגאולה האמיתית והשלימה ע"י משיח צדקנו בשייכות להנהגת אומות העולם -
>   "וכתתו חרבותם לאתים וחניתותיהם למזמרות לא ישא גוי אל גוי חרב ולא ילמדו עוד
>   מלחמה"11.
>
> ולהוסיף, שענין זה יהי' ע"י פעולתו של מלך המשיח עצמו - כמ"ש בהתחלת הפסוק11 "ושפט
>   בין הגוים והוכיח לעמים רבים" )"השופט הוא מלך המשיח . . שיהא אדון כל העמים, והוא
>   יוכיח להם ויאמר למי שימצא בו העול ישר המעוות . . ומפני זה לא תהי' מלחמה בין עם
>   לעם כי הוא ישלים ביניהם, ולא יצטרכו לכלי מלחמה, וכתתו אותם לעשות מהם כלי
>   לעבודת האדמה"12(, שכן, "באחרית הימים נכון יהי' הר בית ה' גו' ונהרו אליו כל הגוים
>   והלכו עמים רבים ואמרו לכו ונעלה אל הר ה' אל בית אלקי יעקב ויורנו מדרכיו ונלכה
>   באורחותיו כי מציון תצא תורה ודבר ה' מירושלים"13, "והמורה הוא מלך המשיח, ועליו
>   נאמר ושפט"12.
>
> וכיון שבימים אלו מחליטים ומכריזים ראשי מדינות בעולם ע"ד צמצום וביטול כלי נשק
>   וההוספה בהענינים הדרושים לקיום כלכלת המדינה והעולם כולו - תוכן היעוד "וכתתו
>   חרבותם לאתים", שבירת כלי המלחמה לעשות מהם כלים לעבודת האדמה, "ארץ14 ממנה
>   יצא לחם"15 - ה"ז סימן ברור על התחלת קיומו של יעוד זה בגאולה האמיתית והשלימה ע"י
>   משיח צדקנו.

In short, the Lubavitcher Rebbe explained that the talks of general disarmament (though I think that the talks discussed were about *Nuclear* weapons) were preparations for the imminent coming of Moshiach.

I suppose it means that the Rebbe supports (*if not stronger*) Nuclear Disarmament.

Comment: was the lubavitcher rebbe a posek? didnt he refuse to pasken shaalos? the op wants poskim

Comment: @Mefaresh ask him if he means only poskim to exlude Rebbes, Rosh Yeshivas or Mashgichim

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv The Lubavitcher Rebbe was a posek, he got semicha from the Rogatchover. He also actively paskened to sheilos that he was asked.

Comment: He also got a semicha from the שרידי אש